# Blindness and Lighting Menorah

Tags: halacha, chanuka, see-sight-vision-blind, menora-chanukia, handicap-disabled-impair

Are the Blind responsible to light the Menorah on Chanukah?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

He is *chayav* (obligated). Therefore if someone else lives in the same home, we have him fulfill his obligation with him by paying him a small amount to partner with him. If he has a wife, she lights for both of them. If not, then he lights with someone helping him (so that he does not hurt himself or start a fire.)

[SA OC 675: 3 MA 4](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14327&st=&pgnum=418)

**סומא** אם יכול להשתתף
בפריטי מוטב ואס
יש לו אשה אשתו מדלקת עליו
ואס אין לו אשה ויש לו בית
מיוחד מדליק ע״י סיוע של
אחר **דסומא חייב בכל המצות**

Answer (score 4):

Rav Aharon Lichtenstein has a broad analysis of this subject. He dealt with the issue personally when his father went blind late in life.
Part I - http://vbm-torah.org/archive/halak66/14halak.htm 
Part II - http://vbm-torah.org/archive/halak66/15halak.htm
Part III - http://vbm-torah.org/archive/halak66/16halak.htm

Answer (score 1):

One of the main reasons we light is for Pirsumei Nisah. It would seem that a blind person also has this obligation.