# Can One be yotzei through a practice he rejects?

Tags: halacha-theory

If, through one's learning, or through a family tradition, one has established a particular practice which flat-out rejects other practices, but then he is put in a situation where his traditional practice is impossible, can he be yotzei his obligation by following the practice he rejects?

For example, if one holds that [horseradish](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/79832/whats-the-deal-with-horseradish-at-the-seder) is not an acceptable way of fulfilling the obligation to eat maror, but he is somewhere where it is the only option, can he be yotzei by eating horseradish because others have a tradition that it is a valid option? I am not talking about a case where there are a bunch of what one sees as valid traditions, but a case in which one rejects the validity of the practice he would be forced to rely on.

[note - I have two or three other potential parallel cases but there are other variables which make them not strictly parallel]

Comment: So what is the actual question here? It sounds like what you are asking is, when are you permitted to violate halacha (what you learned to be correct) or violate your family tradition (אל תטוש תורת אמך)?

Comment: sounds like you need a sort of hatoras nedorim.

Comment: @YaacovDeane would there be a difference between an understanding and an accepted practice that developed from an understanding when it comes to satisfying an active obligation?

Comment: @AvrohomYitzchok that would work if the only thing that bound me was a tradition, not the rejection of other practices as being invalid. Can I fulfill my chiyuv through a practice that I don't accept as valid?

Comment: Do you hold that horseradish is pasul bedieved or not?

Comment: As with many things proving the negative is very difficult. If indeed the answer is that if you know something is wrong, then you shouldn't do it even if all your friends are found it, then there likely saying so, as it would be self evident.

Comment: @mevaqesh my personal understanding (or, possibly, my tradition) is that something is not the right way to be mekayem but according to others, it is a way to be mekayem. If forced, can I be mekayem through something that, while I don't hold by, is acceptable to others.

Comment: @Danno What's the question? Suppose in your example you eat the horseradish, just in case. Either you've been yotzei or not. You believe not, but other people believe yes. Halakha is about what we should _do_. Whether or not we've been _yotzei_ isn't relevant to _halakha_ except to the extent that it determines what we should do next. If you're not going to have an opportunity to do the mitzvah the "right" way, what difference does it make if you were _yotzei_ when you did it the wrong way?

Comment: If it's wrong, it's wrong. Inasmuch as you are certain it is wrong, your performance of it will be meaningless. The fact that someone else is mistaken shouldn't help.

Comment: @Daniel when I make the bracha levatalah.

Comment: @Danno Why make a _bracha_ if you don't believe you're doing the mitzvah right?

Comment: @Daniel because if, regardless of my belief, my action will allow me to be mekayem, why wouldn't I make the bracha?

Comment: I don't understand why its being the only option changes anything. If all you have is safek maror, you should eat it as a safek. @Daniel is right on.

Comment: Did R' Elazar ben Azaria not join the other Tannaim all night even though according to him the chiyuv ends at midnight? (I think that's R' Elazar, anyway. For sure one of them.)