# Why does the Ezras Torah Luach say horseradish is preferred?

Tags: passover, marror-bitter-herbs

The Ezras Torah Luach (in the obvious place) says that horseradish is the best way to fulfill the mitzva of maror.

I've seen [answers](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/79850/11532) on this site that say the opposite: horseradish is a very bedieved option.

What is Ezras Torah's reasoning?

Comment: Likely they are talking about a place where noninfested lettuce is unavailable. It might be their opinion that the USA is such a place. Obviously others might differ.

Comment: Perhaps they refer to horseradish leaves? That's not as hard to justify as the root

Comment: @DoubleAA they refer to it as chrein.  I don't speak Yiddish, but my understanding is that that word is generally used for the ground root?

Comment: Wow! Beats me! Chrein, as far as I know, is horseradish root. I don't know anyone in U.S. that's eating the leaves - certainly not with gefilte fish. My surmisal - Ezras Torah may have had it's minhagim originating from Eastern Europe where romaine lettuce was probably not as readily available. In the U.S., when I was a child, I know of no one who used romaine lettuce for maror - even the most stringent / Hassidim. (My family is not Hassidc, per se, but follow Vishnitz minhag. They all ate horseradish.) Perhaps, E.T. hasn't adapted their text or rules much since 35 - 40 years ago.