# Loss of smell - Borei Menei B’Samim

Tags: halacha, shabbat, havdalah, motzei-shabbos, smell

One of the symptoms of COVID-19 is the loss of smell. Is one still Yotzei their father bracha of Borei Menei B’Samim even if they cannot smell the B’samim?

Comment: If you can't smell, why would you need somebody to be Motzi you, since you're not going to smell anything?

Comment: I'm confused who can't smell: the subject or the father?

Comment: Possible duplicate https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/27265/759

Comment: I learned as part of a shiur that one who cannot smell the besamim should not use it at havdalah. The question is if one is normally yotzi when his father makes havdalah, what if the son cannot smell the besamim.

Comment: Double AA, the subject can't smell. My question is like the second half of sabbahillel