# What are the parameters concerning the use of the menorah lights

Tags: halacha, chanuka, zemanim, minor-katan-child, menora-chanukia

In the song Haneiros Halallu we say that the Chanuka candles are holy and we don't have permission to use them only to view them. I'd like to understand what that means. Do they attain this status irrespective of who lights them? Meaning if someone who is not obligated to light chanuka candles does so (such as a minor or a blind person) do they have the same status? Do they retain this status if they are seen outside of their halachic time, such as very late at night.

Comment: A blind person is not obligated to light chanukkah candles?

Comment: @DoubleAA there is such a view, but IINM we do not rule thus.

Comment: @msh210 Full analysis http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/4262/759

Comment: what about if they were lit without a bracha?

Answer (score 3):

An answer to: Do they retain this status if they are seen outside of their halachic time, such as very late at night?

See [O Ch 674 (1)](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14166&st=&pgnum=289) in the Remo who says  אבל אחר שעבר זמן המצוה מותרים בהנאה  - After the time of the mitzva it is permitted to have benefit from them.